# Cookie value not being updated in .NET after changing in client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, cookies

I've initialized a cookie in jQuery and set it's value to `true`. When I check the cookie in .NET/C#:

```
Request.Cookies["test"].Value.toString();
```

I can see that the value is indeed true as expected. The problem that I wasn't to see the new value of the cookie when changing it to `false`. Using a chrome extension I can see that the value was changed to false, but in .NET when I read the Cookie value it's still true.

I assume that something happens from the time I updated the cookie in the client and the time the page got back.

Any reason why I can't see the changed value in the cookie on the server side?

BTW: the cookie was created on the client side, not on the server side.

JS:

```
var a = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(a === 0){
      $.cookie('test','true');
   }
   else{
      $.cookie('test','false');
    }
});
```

In chrome the cookie shows:

[image]

Putting a breakpoint at the line that reads the cookie value and right after checking the value of the cookie (as "true") in Chrome, .NET shows the value as "false".

Comment: When are you reading the cookie? On post back after you change the value?

Comment: @epascarello on page load

Comment: Can you show the code where you create and modify the cookie, then post?

Comment: @epascarello $.cookie('test', 'true');

Comment: You need to show more code...

Comment: I will put the code in the question body

Comment: @epascarello I load the page with a===1 and it set the cookie to false. The cookie shows "false" when I read it on the server. When I set the a===0, hard refresh the page and it changes the value of the cookie to "true", but on pageLoad on the server I see the cookie value as "false", not "true". I inspected the cookie while putting a breakpoint on the server, and the cookie is "true", and .NET reads it as "false".

Comment: @epascarello, I think I was able to found the issue. I needed to use $.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' }); instead just $.cookie('name','value'). Seems to work, doing some extra checking though.